# Send notification over game

Tags: 14.04, notification

I use `Ubuntu 14.04` and know I can send a notification to the screen by executing this command in a shell (.sh) script:

```
notify-send "Task complete."
```

But it does not seem when another application (for example a game) is in fullscreen mode. How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `-u critical` to your `notify-send`, e.g.

`notify-send -u critical "Task complete."`

You can also specify other levels of urgency (low, normal, critical).